# Android - No such field error in facebook sdk

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-sdk-4.x

I'm trying to integrate Facebook SDK in my android app. I downloaded `facebook-android-sdk-4.5.1` and followed the steps in the developer guide. As I'm trying to run the sample `HelloFacebookSample` placed in the samples folder of the SDK, I'm getting the following error:

```
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277): java.lang.NoSuchFieldError:     java.util.Locale.ROOT
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.loadDefaultsFromMetadata(FacebookSdk.java:623)
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:203)
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.facebook.FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(FacebookSdk.java:173)
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.example.image.HelloFacebookSampleActivity.onCreate(HelloFacebookSampleActivity.java:117)
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-31 18:37:19.399: E/AndroidRuntime(277):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I'm trying Android 2.2. Is this an issue? Or anything I missed? Can someone guide me please.

Comment: Have you tried on different devices (OS versions)? maybe using genymotion? if this is always reproducible then you might have an issue with your IDE and/or environment

Answer (score 0):

The Facebook SDK requires a minimum Android API version 15 (Android 4.0.3, or ICE CREAM SANDWICH).

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android

Comment: What is wrong with my answer? It's factual and even backed up by a reference which confirms this fact.

Comment: Nothing is wrong with your answer. Probably someone was just lazy enough to read carefully the question and see that OP uses Android 2.2 (API level 8), while FB SDK **requires** API 15 as it was pointed by you.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying Android 2.2. Is this an issue?

Yes, since FB 4.5.1 SDK required API 9 to run (that is Android 2.3). You can check it here: https://web.archive.org/web/20150821025823/https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android

> Requires Android API 9.

It can't be run on previous Android versions since it uses new API methods/fields (in your case exception is caused by accessing the `Locale.ROOT` constant which was added only in API 9).

Starting from version 4.6.0 FB SDK started to require API 15:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/upgrading-4.x